# Can't access web server with public IP

Tags: ip, web

I am running spring boob/tomcat web server on raspberry pi, and I can access that same server from another computer when I use a private IP address(192.168....), but when I try to access it with public IP from another network, it is just loading...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is your firewall configured to allow incoming connections from outside your LAN?

Comment: Hi, welcome, great question. The solution involves configuring firewall/router to (port) forward the public requests to the web server (the pi's private ip). I suggest updating your question to include any steps you've taken along this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about private IP and public IP, then NAT (Network Address Translation) must be involved somewhere (probably on your router).

By design, you cannot connect to an internal network (the one "inside" NAT, using private addresses) from external network (ie. outside the router) "just so", because your router uses **only one** public IP address for **all** private IP addresses of all devices that could exist in your network. So, if a connection comes from outside, the router has no way to know where it should direct the connection to.

You must tell this to your router. To do this, you use a function on your router called port forwarding. You must check with your router manual how to configure this. You have to specify a port for incoming connection (eg. 80 for HTTP), and to what internal IP address and what port should the connection be redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It turned out that my Internet provider changed my public IP address, now that I contacted them everything works, btw. I have all ports figured out, thanks once again for an answer